# Build standard R model objects from parameters

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have at my disposition the parameters for a simple logistic model, without having access to the training data set. So, I am trying to build a standard R model object for logistic regression by specifying its a0 and beta parameters. My aim is to observe the behavior of the model. Predict function can easily be replaced with `1/(1+e^(-a_0-beta.x))`, but I would like to use other, more complexes functions of model objects.

My needs is something like that:

```
model <- glm(parameters = c(a0, beta), family = 'binomial', link = 'logistic')
```

How would it be possible to build a standard R model object from a set of parameters (`a0` and `beta`) and `family` / `link` function ?

Comment: Maybe you can modify code of the `glm` function to create a `glm_custom` that fits your new inputs

Comment: you could simulate the data perfectly and then feed it to a glm model

Comment: "*I would like to use other, more complexes functions of model objects*" this is pretty vague, can you be more specific? Many parts of the model object are specifically related to training data, fitted values, residuals, standard errors... Do you want to input parameters *only*? Do you want to add in a VCOV matrix so that you can calculate uncertainty in predictions? What else do you want to do?

Comment: Yes, only parameters, the goal is to use some of the of the explanatory functions from the iml package, with new X values.

Comment: @Jonny Phelps: that would be worth a nobel prize...